# generating reports in rails like crystal report in VB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm looking for a way to generate reports from view, like suppose I have model named "User" having fields "first_name, last_name,email, user_name ".
I will be having a view in which I will be having 2 select field, first one having model names and second one will be multiple select box where I can select model attribute that I can show in report.

How to generate report for selected attribute of specific model?

Comment: You mean a “set up view” where a user select options to generate a “report view”? If this is the case, maybe you can set session variables or use a model to store settings if you need to saved for longer.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd hardcode both select tags as not every field on the model might be worth filtering for. But for the sake of your question, ActiveRecord allows you to ask for the columns a model has in the database, e.g.

```
User.column_names
```

or

```
User.columns
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas for responding. This one I know but I'm looking for some report generating tool same as we have in asp.net named "Crystal report".

Comment: sorry, never heard of that.